# SQL issue in AWS (Only in a specific place)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm unable to connect SQL server in AWS EC2. This issue only happens in Qatar. I'm able to connect it in India, Dubai, Muscat and Saudi. They are using 4G, I asked them to connect to ordinary broadband, still not working. Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you connecting directly to the SQL Server? Its very likely port filtering may be involved. If they can connect over a different port, you may need to proxy the connect via that port to the SQL server.

Comment: Yes, I'm directly giving the serverip\sqlexpress to the SQL. I changed Security groups to All Traffic.

Comment: Also please refer how may be the solution to connect through proxy. (And the curious thing is, the issue occurs only in a specific nation. Tried 4G and broadband)

Comment: This may not have anything to do with your security setup. In some countries that filter access to the internet, like Qatar, they may be blocking access to certian ip blocks, or filtering certian ports.

Comment: First, see if they are being blocked access to amazon or just the port. Enable ICMP on your security group and have them ping the IP.

Comment: Thank you for taking time in this discussion-
Remote Desktop connection is working there. I am able to ping the server and in tracert, there was an issue while using 4G (a modem without port forwarding), but it was okay in broadband. Still SQL is not getting connected. 
(At last I was able to connect through Amazon RDS, but all our operation was in EC2, and RDS was a temporary solution. ) Please help me in finding a solution in AWS EC2.

Comment: I suppose there are probably a couple of options depending which ports are filtered. You will probably need a new ec2 instance to work as a proxy. Basically you need to take connection on a port that works, and forward them to the sql server port on the other instance. You may be able to use a load balancer (though i'm not sure an RDS instance can be attached) here since it behaves like a proxy.

Comment: Good, that will be a good option. I will try that. I will give them the new IP.